# Basics of probability, randomly selection without repetition

Tags: probability

There are **n** pineapples **m** bananas and **k** apples in the bowl  (n,m,k >=10). You take 10 fruits randomly and without repetition.
X-the number of selected pineapples. Y-the number of selected bananas. Z-the number of selected apples.
QUESTION: For **m=n=k=10** calculate the P(X=5,Y=2).
ANSWER: {C(10,5)C(10,2)C(10,3)}/C(30,10)....Why there is a need to divide by 30 choose 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you want the probability. The numerator is the number of ways to select $5$ pineapples, $2$ bananas and $3$ apples. To get the probability of one of these selections being made, you need to divide this by the total number of equiprobable selections of $10$ out of $30$ fruits.